# Are We Closer Kin Than First Cousins?

Tags: dna

I had a match on Ancestry of a lady who was adopted as a baby, who is looking for her birth parents. She is my age. She matched at 1111 across 45 DNA segments! I know that is in range that is more than my known first cousins on the same tree! Even my cousin who is doubly-related! [888]. She tested less with him, but still in range of first cousins. Why so high? It must be one of my two uncles [my mom's brothers], nether had living   offspring  of their own and are deceased, as is my mother. I elimated my aunts because they were married  and having their own families at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Entering your shared [1111 Centimorgans into the Shared cM Project tool](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1111) at DNA Painter suggests first cousin is one of the most likely relationships.

There are a number of other possibilities, as you will see by clicking the link above, but they mostly come from other generations.